# What does the Geth/Erigon ethereum client do if there are not enough transactions in the pool to fully fill the new creating block?

Tags: go-ethereum, blocks

When the transaction pool of Ethereum nodes like Geth or Erigon doesn't have enough transactions to completely fill a new block, how do these nodes respond? Do they immediately generate a partially filled (partially empty) block, or do they wait for a certain period for new transactions to arrive before creating the block?